# my ajax send post is not working in JS

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I have a wordrpess site and I am trying to do an ajax call to send a variable but I cant make it work when I try to retrieve the variable I dont get anything back this is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            window.onload = function(){
            var boton = document.getElementsByClassName("teatro-buy");
            const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();


            xhr.onload = function ()
            {
                console.log(this.responseText); 
            }
            for (let qq = 0; qq < boton.length; qq++) 
            {

                            boton[qq].onclick = function() 
                            { 

                                 botonid =  this.id ;

                              xhr.open("POST", "ajaxcallnew.php")
                              xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                              xhr.send("lol=" + botonid);
                              console.log(botonid);





                            }

            } 

        };

</script>
```

and this is my php

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['lol'])){ //check if $_POST['examplePHP'] exists
        echo $_POST['lol']; // echo the data
        die(); // stop execution of the script.
    }

?>
```

Comment: You're not doing anything with the response? What do you expect the code to do?

Comment: to send the variable boton id as $_POST['lol'];

Comment: And how do you know that it’s not doing that?

Comment: I've just recreated your sample on PHPFiddle and it works, so check developer tools in your browser (javascript step by step debugger and network tab), maybe `getElementsByClassName` doesn't pick anything.

Comment: it does work because when I do console log I get the result but when I check on the php page nothing is set..:(

Comment: Then I don't get what you are trying to do. The code you provided works as expected. What do you mean by "nothing is set"?

Answer (score 1):

1. you can var_dump($_POST) or var_dump($_SERVER) or echo 1 ... if it's empty, your request is not arrive php
2. you can read the server log (such as nginx log, apache log ... almost they exist in runtime folder)
3. check your format:

   examples:

   (1) get:

   ```
   var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
   ajax.open('get','getStar.php?starName='+name);
   ajax.send();
   xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
       if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
           console.log(xhr.responseText);
       } 
   };
   ```

   (2) post:

   ```
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   xhr.open('post', '02.post.php' );
   xhr.send('name=fox&age=18');
   xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
       if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
           console.log(xhr.responseText);
       } 
   };
   ```

Answer (score 0):

you must add to your request action property.

For example:

```
jQuery.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl, // ('admin-ajax.php')
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {action: 'yourvalue', fields: info},
            success: function (json) {
                console.log(json)
        });
```

and on `functions.php` add the following:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_actionValue', 'FunkName');
add_action("wp_ajax_actionValue", 'FunkName');
function FunkName()
{
   //buisness logic
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not use jQuery for this. It would become very simple.

```js
$.ajax({
 url:'path_to_php_file.php',
 type:'post',
 data:{'lol':'value_for_lol'},
 onsuccess:function(response){
    alert(response);
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp